# Hover image on top of another image

Tags: css

I'm trying to add some hover effect on some images I got.

```
<div id="horizontal_list">
  <div class="grid_3 first overlay">
      <a href="#">
        <img border="0" alt="first" src="path">
      </a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_3 overlay">
      <a href="#">
        <img border="0" alt="first" src="path">
      </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I hover the div with the overlay class I want another image to hover on top of the imagetag..

I've got the following css:

```
#horizontal_list{
margin-top: 18px;
height: 330px;
}

.grid_3{
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}   
.first{
        margin-left: 0px !important;
    }

.last{
    margin-right: 0px !important;
}

.overlay{
    height: 330px;
}

.overlay:hover{
    background: url('path') no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'imagetag' but here is what I think you mean:

What you can do, is adding the second image in your html:

```
<div id="horizontal_list">
  <div class="grid_3 first overlay">
      <a href="#">
        <img class="first_img" border="0" alt="first" src="path">
        <img class="sec_img" border="0" alt="second" src="path">
      </a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_3 overlay">
      <a href="#">
        <img class="first_img" border="0" alt="first" src="path">
        <img class="sec_img" border="0" alt="second" src="path">
      </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in your CSS:

```
.overlay {position: relative;}
.overlay:hover a img.sec_img {display: none;}
.overlay:hover a img.sec_img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: url(path) no-repeat;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: [imgwidth]px;
  height: [imgheight]px;
}
```

Be sure to change [imgwidth] and [imgheight] into the correct dimensions.

Comment: hmm.. I still want to show the original image.. The second image is a transparent overlay..

Comment: Do the images that you still want to show (beneath the transparent overlay) have a fixed height?

Comment: yes, all of the images I want to hover got equal height and width.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
 <div class="hoverholder">
      <a href="#" class="picone">
        <img src="#" alt="" />
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="pictwo">
        <img src="#" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.pictwo {display:none;}

.hoverholder:hover .picone{
  display:none;
}

.hoverholder:hover .pictwo{
  display:block;
}
```